# How can I list unique values within a date range?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, unique

In sheet 1 I have a list of project codes in column A and dates in column B.

In sheet 2, I'm trying to generate a list from sheet 1 of unique project codes from column A within certain dates from column B. I would like to be able to change this date range easily based on the date range in sheet 2 between cell D2 and E2.

[image]

[image]

I have tried the following formula and have not been able to get the result I need:

`=if(">="&$D$2,"<="&$E$2,unique('Sheet 1'!$A$2:$A))`

This returns the following:

[image]

and this:

`=UNIQUE(FILTER('Sheet 1'!$A$2:$A,'Sheet 1'!$B$2:$B,">="&$D$2,'Sheet 1'!$B$2:$B,">="&$E$2))`

which returns this:

[image]

Can anyone help?

Edit:

I have tried using the formula:

`=UNIQUE(FILTER('Sheet 1'!A2:A,'Sheet 1'!B2:B>=D2,'Sheet 1'!B2:B>=E2))`

This appeared to work initially however when I added additional project codes to column A in sheet 1 these did not appear.

I edited the formula to:

`=UNIQUE(FILTER('Sheet 1'!A2:A,'Sheet 1'!B2:B>=1/1/2023,'Sheet 1'!B2:B>=30/1/2023))`

This gave the results I was looking for however I would really like to be able to use date ranges that I can change in cells D2 and E2 in sheet 2 in the formula rather than dates.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER('Sheet 1'!A2:A,'Sheet 1'!B2:B>=D2,'Sheet 1'!B2:B<=E2))
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help again, I tried the formula and it appeared to work however I came across some problems that I have outlined in the edited questions above. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, I have figured out the problem by changing > to < in the final part of the formula. Many thanks

Comment: yeah.. `lesser than` end date!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Query too:

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY('Sheet 1'!A2:B, "Select A where B > date '"&TEXT(D2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and B <= date '"&TEXT(E2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"))
```